# Selecting Files from folder using Regular Expression c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-negation

I have a case there i want to select a set of file based on a patter.So i need a regular expression which following all these scenarios. **It should contain a word "Price"**

```
Price_{0}_Extract_{1}.xml
```

I want to handle following scenarios

```
Price_ABC_Extract_20150723081513.xml 
Price_DEF_Extract_20150823081513.xml 
ABC_Price_DEF_Extract_20150823081513.xml
FGH_Price_DEF_Extract_20150823081513_1.xml
```

Using one regular expression i want to select above files

**`{1}` should be always in a format `"yyyyMMddHHmmss"`**
  It should always contain a word "Price"

Can anyone help on this. Curently i am using one regular expression which is not handling all these case( ie `Price_[yyyyMMddHHmmss].xml`)

**i need a solution which is working in c#**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex to check for file name matches:

`^\w*?Price_\w*?Extract_\d{14}(?:_\d+?)??\.xml$`
[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/dN8zU7/2).

However it doesn't verify the date is actually valid, only that it takes up the correct number of digits.

Comment: date should be always in format yyyyMMddHHmmss.how can we include this condition also [yyyyMMddHHmmss] ???

Comment: @vmb Regex has no knowledge of years, months and days. The best you can do is put numeric restrictions on them to make sure they do not exceed a certain range (eg. outside of 1-31 day of the month).

Answer (score 0):

Adding numeric restrictions to JB's answer:

\w*?Price_\w*?\d{4}[0-1]\d[0-3]\d[0-2]\d[0-6]\d[0-6]\d(?:_\d+?)??.xml

Comment: but i want to keep [yyyyMMddHHmmss] in regex